# Cropping images sometimes a wrong area

Tags: c#, image, graphics, png, crop

I'm using [jQuery-cropbox](https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox) to crop images on a web application.

Everything is running smoothly most of the time, but from time to time, the generated image is wrong, as if the cropping was applied with wrong coordinates.

As an example, consider this [image](http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/transparent-animals6.png) :

[image]

In cropbox, I zoom and drag until I get this :

[image]

But when I click on the crop button, it gives me this:

[image]

Here is the cropping code:

```
private Bitmap CropImage(Image img, Rectangle rect)
{
    Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
    g.DrawImage(img, -rect.X, -rect.Y);

    return newImg;
}

//...

// save image
var streamOut = new MemoryStream();
Bitmap newImg = CropImage(oldImg, rect);
newImg.Save(streamOut, ImageFormat.Png);
```

`oldImg` is the image previously posted, `rect` the coordinates I use to crop.

I checked the coordinates in rect of course, they are correct.

For reference, to obtain the result provided the coordinates are (those may not be exactly accurate, I took them from a second test, so I certainly placed the picture a bit differently):

```
x: 47
y: 94
w: 150
h: 150
```

What is happening ?

Comment: My money is on DPI issue. Use the overload of `DrawImage` which accepts a complete `Rectangle`, and not just location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. The result is once again different though (!)

Comment: Try this one specifically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2s2a44c(v=vs.110).aspx and pass in `GraphicsUnit.Pixel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image (as posted) has 72dpi; your screen and therefore the Graphics you use probably have 96dpi.

This will lead to the effect you see.

To avoid the effect simply set the resolution of `img` before drawing it to the one in your Graphics object:

```
img.SetResolution((int)g.DpiX, (int)g.DpiY);
```

Comment: Good catch. I'll edit my question to make it a bit more related to the answer, so it can help future readers. Thanks!

Comment: That's a good idea, please do! - +1 for that! (And for the cute image ;-)