# C# Cropping image return wrong coordinates

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, crop

I've been trying to crop a specific image using Selenium and different cropping methods for a few days.

**An important note before my code - the following method used to work 2 weeks ago and for some reason it now returns an image with wrong coordinates**

```
// Go to site
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
Screenshot screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray))
using (var imgShot = Image.FromStream(ms))
using (var src = new Bitmap(imgShot))
      {
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//canvas"));
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);

        var clone = src.Clone(cropRect, src.PixelFormat);
        clone.Save(filePath);
      }
```

Things I tried:

1) I usually use Firefox driver for this purpose, I tried using ChromeDriver instead and got the same result.

2) I checked for the element's coordiantes using the following console command: $0.getBoundingClientRect() and the position I got in my code matches it.

3) I tried 4 different cropping methods including this one:

```
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//canvas"));
string filename = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.png";
Screenshot screenshot = Driver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename, ImageFormat.Png);

Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y,
    element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);

using (Image imgShot = Image.FromFile(filename))
using (Bitmap original = new Bitmap(imgShot))
using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(original, new Size(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height)))
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
        cropRect,
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    target.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Just to be clear, the image I get is totally blank. In a different website the image I get is not blank so I can tell it's just in the wrong coordinates.

4) I tried a different website and different elements and they were all in the wrong coordinates.

5) I tried to Google it and found so many different approaches that didn't work. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26649763/3450204) however, says something about resolution which was my best guess. I tried playing with both the original and the target's resolution and saw no difference. The set resolution method was called either before or after the Graphics variable was created and still, zero change.

The funny thing is, it used to work 2 weeks ago but I never changed the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the thing that actually changed 2 weeks ago wasn't my code but the Firefox version installed on my machine. The current version - v52, return elements in wrong coordinates.
Uninstalling it and reinstalling the previous version - v47 solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a blank image probably because the area is not yet rendered when `GetScreenshot` is called.
Try to wait to see if it's the case:

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)element).GetScreenshot();
```

It could also be due to the implementation in the page preventing web scrapers, in which case there's nothing much you can do without digging in the code.

Note that you shouldn't use `element.Location` since it returns the coordinates relative to the document and not from the viewport.
You should also consider calling `GetScreenshot` directly on a `IWebElement` if the driver supports it.

Here's a working example to capture a footer:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions";

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#footer"));

string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), @"screenshot.png");

try {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)element).GetScreenshot();
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}
catch (WebDriverException) {

    var result = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
      "var elm = arguments[0];" +
      "elm.scrollIntoView(true);" +
      "var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();" +
      "return [rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height];"
      , element);

    int[] pts = Array.ConvertAll(((IReadOnlyCollection<object>)result).ToArray(), Convert.ToInt32);
    var rect = new Rectangle(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]);

    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

    using (var mstream = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray))
    using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mstream, false, false)) {
        rect.Intersect(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));

        if (rect.IsEmpty)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cropping rectangle is out of range.");

        var clone = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        clone.Save(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering, does the above example work for you? I tried this exact example. Seems that my driver does not support taking screenshots from direct elements and also I still get an element in a wrong coordinates.

Comment: Yes, this example works for me. The chrome driver doesn't yet support an element screenshot, but the gecko driver does. You should first try to determine if it is due to the coordinates returned by `getBoundingClientRect()` or due the screenshot itself. Also make sure that you are selecting the right element and that all your drivers are up to date. From the information you provided, there's no way to tell exactly what is wrong.

Comment: My Firefox's version is up to date is so is my GeckoDriver. Could you provide your versions please, so I try them out and may finally see a difference

Comment: I use chromedriver v2.30.477700 with Chrome v59.0.3071.86 on windows 10 x64.